# Code runs as wanted, but an error message still pops up after outputing the correct definition (Python)

Tags: python

**Apologies, I am new to coding so this might seem simple for some.**

```
from PyDictionary import PyDictionary

dictionary=PyDictionary("hotel")


x = dictionary.printMeanings()
x = x.split()
y = x.pop()
y = y.join("")
print(y)
```

The error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
    File "main.py", line 7, in <module> 
       x = x.split() 
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Comment: `an error message still pops up`: Care to post the error message?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "main.py", line 7, in <module>
        x = x.split()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: Edit your question and post the full traceback. Always post the *whole error message* with *full traceback*. It means that `.printMeanings()` returns `None`, not a string.

Comment: sorry, i have now - i clicked enter and it posted the comment when i thought it would make a new line

Answer (score 2):

You'll get good at reading error messages.  In this case, the message is telling you exactly what's up:

```
(6) x = dictionary.printMeanings()
(7) x = x.split()
```

It is complaining about line 7, `x = x.split()`.  It is saying that `x` contains a value of type `NoneType`.  This type can only have one value, the value `None`, so it's telling you that `x` contains `None`.  You're trying to call `.split()` on this `None` value. You can't call `.split()` on a `None`. It's telling you that too, and that's why Python raised this particular exception.

What you can take from that is that the call to `dictionary.printMeanings()` on line 6 is returning `None`.  Since you're calling `.split()` on the result returning that method, you must think it returns a string.  It doesn't.  It doesn't return anything. That's what getting back `None` means.

Answer (score 1):

This is very often confusing to new programmers: What you see on the screen (i.e., what `print()` **outputs**) is not the same as what print **returns** to the Python running program.

Basically, most functions and operations, e.g. `string.split()` or 2+2, return a value (which you can assign to a variable), but print nothing to the output. `print` sends something to the output but returns nothing. A few functions do both.

In Python, returning "nothing" means you actually return None, so that's what ends up in the variable `x`.